# How to link Bluemix Liberty for Java to jazzhub git repo?

Tags: websphere-liberty, ibm-cloud, ibm-jazz, devops

In the Bluemix dashboard I created a Liberty for Java app and added a git repository to it.

A helpful team member removed this original app.
Our code is still available under the jazzhub repository and it looks like I can still deploy to other Liberty for Java runtimes using the dev ops in jazzhub but there is no link from my Bluemix dashboard to jazzhub (just the option to add/create another git repo).

https://i.stack.imgur.com/CL0bu.jpg (imgur link as not enough rep).

Is there a way to link this within another Liberty for Java app?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple enough:

1. Open your Liberty App in DevOps
2. Click on "BUILD & DEPLOY" button in menu
3. Click play button (triangular button with circle) on the "Build Stage" tile
4. App will build and deploy the app to Bluemix, with a link between the app and the repo in DevOps

Enjoy

Answer (score 1):

If you deploy the app again from DevOps Services it will re-add the link to the Bluemix dashboard.